# How to connect to a git repo and run git commands in sagemaker studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have set up a sagemaker studio , opened a terminal and cloned a project from gitlab repo, over https.

```
git clone https://somegilaburl/project
```

I dont' have access to save ssh keys, so i want to save my credentials as aws secret in secrets manager and use that from a jupyter notebook (not just terminal), to issue git pull/push commands. are there any examples of how to do this from a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-lifecycle-config-examples/blob/main/scripts/set-git-credentials/on-jupyter-server-start.sh) of achieving this through Lifecycle scripts:

> ````
> ## Parameters 
> # your git provider, e.g. github.com GIT_PROVIDER="github.com" GIT_USERNAME="<provide your username here>" AWS_REGION="us-west-2"
> # Secret name stored in AWS Secrets Manager AWS_SECRET_NAME="my-git-credentials"
> # Secret key name inside the secret AWS_SECRET_KEY="github.com"
>
> ## Script Body
>
> PYTHON_EXEC=$(command -v python) cat > ~/.aws-credential-helper.py
> <<EOL
> #!$PYTHON_EXEC
>
> import sys
> import json
> import boto3
> import botocore
>
> GIT_PROVIDER='$GIT_PROVIDER' GIT_USERNAME='$GIT_USERNAME'
> AWS_REGION='$AWS_REGION' AWS_SECRET_NAME='$AWS_SECRET_NAME'
> AWS_SECRET_KEY='$AWS_SECRET_KEY'
>
> if len(sys.argv) < 2 or sys.argv[1] != 'get':
>     exit(0)
>
> credentials = {} for line in sys.stdin:
>     if line.strip() == "":
>         break
>     key, value = line.split('=')[0:2]
>     credentials[key.strip()] = value.strip()
>
> if credentials.get('host', '') == GIT_PROVIDER and \
>     credentials.get('username', '') == GIT_USERNAME:
>     client = boto3.client('secretsmanager', region_name=AWS_REGION)
>     try:
>         response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=AWS_SECRET_NAME)
>     except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
>         exit(1)
>     if 'SecretString' in response:
>         secret = response['SecretString']
>         secret_dict = json.loads(secret)
>         if AWS_SECRET_KEY in secret_dict:
>             credentials['password'] = secret_dict[AWS_SECRET_KEY]
>
> for key, value in credentials.items():
>     print('{}={}'.format(key, value))
>
> EOL
>
> chmod +x ~/.aws-credential-helper.py git config --global
> credential.helper ~/.aws-credential-helper.py ```
> ````

You can run line 52-63(after importing boto3) to get the secrets on a notebook as well.